# How to rewrite urls on a multilingual website, with different domain names?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've made an international website where languages are available like this :

> www.sitename.com/es/spanishpage.html
>   www.sitename.com/de/germanpage.html
>   www.sitename.com/fr/frenchpage.html
>   ...

All lang folders are virtual, so i can make hundreds versions with the same number of PHP pages. To do so i use rewrite rules to create the pages, something similar to this :

```
RewriteRule ^germanpage\.html$ /page.php?lang=de [L]
```

Now i'd like to use real domain names. How can i do that please ?
I think I have to create physical folders (de/, /fr/ ...) for domains, but then how i rewrite the pages?

I mean, sitename.de/ goes to myserver.com/de/ . It works, but it's an empty folder. How can i redirect all the website to my pages located at myserver.com/page.php?lang=de please ?

Thanks a lot for you help ! I'm really lost.

nb. don't know if it's iportant, but the site is running on a dedicated server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I found consist in setting all the domains under the server root, and then simply put redirects without the virtual folders.

so for mydomain.com/de/germanpage.html

This rule :

```
RewriteRule ^de/germanpage\.html$ page.php?lang=de
```

Becomes :

```
RewriteRule ^germanpage\.html$ page.php?lang=de
```

There must an easier solution (because now i can't have .de/contact.html and .fr/contact.html) but at least it works.

Answer (score -1):

you can use soft links instead of creating physical folders.
[Click here to find out more about Symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link)

Go to root folder at your domain (let say you have index.php in your root folder)
myserver.com

now execute following commands

```
ln -s es
ln -s de
ln -s fr
```

now if you access http://myserver.com/fr/index.php 
file that will be executed is
http://myserver.com/index.php

Comment: Thanks but i really don't understand how it could work in this case. Do you have a concrete example please ? Thx

Comment: Thanks shankhan, i see what you mean ! But it already works like that using .htaccess.
What i want to do is http://mygerman site.de/pageingerman.html to be executed in myserver.com/page.php?lang=de
Don't know how to do that.

Comment: are all sites like site.de, site.fr and myserver.com hosted on the same server if so why don't u just set all sites documentroot to same folder

Comment: in fact what you tell me to do is to put all my domain names to myserver.com/
And there, with a .htaccess, to make something like that :
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.de$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/de/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /de/$1

Am i right ?

(thanks a lot for your time!)